# Recommended way to do math on database to show in template in Django

Tags: python, django

I need to get some data from the database, do some calculation and show the results in the template.

From my research I saw that I could use django-mathfilters. But I read that it is not recommeded to include business logic in the template. So I researched for alternatives.

It seems that I could use annotate. So I have tried this:

```
def price_supplier(request):
    list = request.GET.get("list")
    price_list = SupplierPriceList.objects.filter(id=list).annotate(margin=(F('cod_product.sale_price') - F('price')) / F('cod_product.sale_price')).all()
    return render(request, 'painel_fornecedor/comparacao_precos.html', {'price_list': price_list})
```

I have tested this and got the error "Cannot resolve keyword 'cod_product.sale_price' into field."
How is the recommended way to implement this?

Here is the model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    cod_product= models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    descripction = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)

class SupplierPriceList(models.Model):
    cod_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10, blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the list you're testing on have a Product associated?

Comment: I think you need to remove the cod_ from your F function. Just `f('product.sale_price'). cod_product is the field, you want the table 'product'

Comment: @BernardoDuarte, yes, it does have a Product associated

Comment: @AMG, I got the same error using f('product.sale_price')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a related field you need to use `__` instead of `.` as a [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
def price_supplier(request):
    list = request.GET.get("list")
    price_list = SupplierPriceList.objects.filter(id=list).annotate(
        margin=(F('cod_product__sale_price') - F('price')) / F('cod_product__sale_price')
    ).all()
    return render(request, 'painel_fornecedor/comparacao_precos.html', {'price_list': price_list})
```

Comment: Ok. Thanks!
So you think that using annotate is the best way to do this?

Comment: @ClaudioShigueoWatanabe I believe it is, since you'll be doing all the work on the DB.